# Why does this Java program fail to run properly? Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game I read about in a Java book. However the code always returns an error and I cannot figure out why. I am relatively new to coding so if the answer is obvious don't rub it in my face :). Also, no errors are displayed in the code in NetBeansIDE so I do not know what is causing the program to fail to run.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TTT{
private String[][] tttBoard;
private String player1, player2;
public TTT(){
    player1 = "X";
    player2 = "O";
    tttBoard = new String[3][3];
    for(int row = 0; row < tttBoard.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < tttBoard.length; col++){
            tttBoard[row][col] = " ";
        }
    }
}
public void play(){
    String currPlayer = player1;
    int movesMade = 0;

    do{
        displayBoard();
        makeMove(currPlayer);
        movesMade += 1;
        if (currPlayer == player1){
            currPlayer = player2;
        }
        else{
            currPlayer = player1;
        }
    }while (movesMade <= 9 && winner() == " ");
    displayBoard();
    System.out.println("Winner is "+winner());
}
public void displayBoard(){
    for(int row = 0; row < tttBoard.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < tttBoard.length; row++){
            System.out.println("["+tttBoard[row][col]+"]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
private void makeMove (String player){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validMove = false;
    int row, col;

    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a row number (0, 1, 2): ");
        row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a column number (0, 1, 2): ");
        col = input.nextInt();
        if((row >= 0 && row < tttBoard.length && col >= 0 && col < 
   tttBoard[0].length) && tttBoard[row][col].equals(" ")){
            tttBoard[row][col] = player;
            validMove = true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid move. Try again.");
        }
    }while(!validMove);
}
private String winner(){
    for(int row = 0; row < tttBoard.length; row++){
        if(tttBoard[row][0].equals(tttBoard[row][1]) && tttBoard[row] 
    [1].equals(tttBoard[row][2]) && !(tttBoard[row][0].equals(" "))){
            return(tttBoard[row][0]);
        }
    }
    for(int col = 0; col < tttBoard[0].length; col++){
        if (tttBoard[0][col].equals(tttBoard[1][col]) && tttBoard[1] 
  [col].equals(tttBoard[2][col]) && (!tttBoard[0][col].equals(" "))){
            return(tttBoard[0][col]);
        }
    }
    if(tttBoard[0][0].equals(tttBoard[1][1]) && tttBoard[1] 
 [1].equals(tttBoard[2][2]) && !(tttBoard[0][0].equals(" "))){
        return(tttBoard[0][0]);
    }
    if(tttBoard[0][2].equals(tttBoard[1][1]) && tttBoard[1] 
 [1].equals(tttBoard[2][0]) && !(tttBoard[0][2].equals(" "))){
        return(tttBoard[0][2]);
    }
    return(" ");
}
}
```

The file that calls and runs it is as follows:

```
public class TicTacToe{
public static void main (String args[]){
    TTT TTTGame = new TTT();
    TTTGame.play();
}
}
```

Comment: You do know that this is not good code: `winner() == " "`, right? You use `.equals(...)`. Not sure if this is causing problems *now*, but even if not, it will cause problems *later*.

Answer (score 0):

Your displayBoard function is wrong. Notice the line:

```
for(int col = 0; col < tttBoard[row].length; col++)
```

You need to get the current row `tttBoard[row]` length. Another error that you made, is that you are incrementing the `row` instead of the `col` variable on the second `for`.

```
public void displayBoard(){
    for(int row = 0; row < tttBoard.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < tttBoard[row].length; col++){
            System.out.println("["+tttBoard[row][col]+"]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```